# It's normal for NSView/UIView to have a datasource?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

For example, I have a custom view that draws a function plot. 
First, I need to get function parameters from the user.
After I need to calculate x/y and draw this point on view.
So, can I use datasource for this view to draw plot in `-drawRect:`? Or it against the MVC pattern?

Comment: Yes even `UITableView` has a datasource and a delegate and its not against MVC pattern. _It is important to note that both the view and the controller depend on the model. However, the model depends on neither the view nor the controller_ [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you're subclassing NSView and creating a custom class that draws plots? If so then yes this is the correct design pattern. For example NSTableView is designed like this. You would tend to draw things that DON'T need a datasource in the `drawRect:` method. Then call on the datasource outside the `drawRect:` method e.g. in a `reloadData` method.

EDIT reload data example:

```
- (void)reloadData{
    if([datasource respondsToSelector:@selector(points:)]) {
        for(NSValue *value in [datasource points]) {
            NSPoint point = value.pointValue;
            // Setup layer here and add to view.layer
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose Data Source provides `CGPoint` array for plot. So, then I call `reloadData` I need to copy this array to custom view's array property? It's correct?

Comment: How are you drawing your plots (scatter graph?)? I tend to use `CALayer`s setup and added from the `reloadData` method. See my edited answer for code.

Comment: datasource returns `CGPathRef` and I stroke this path using `CGContextStrokePath`. It all happens in '-drawRect:`

Answer (score 2):

This question would be better for http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

The answer is yes use a data source. Create a protocol for your view like `UITableViewDataSource` is for `UITableView`. You may also want a delegate, like `UITableViewDelegate` is for `UITableView`.